# How to read and save in a variable part of a txt in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I have been looking for some answers about this subject but I only see stuffs like: read something with spaces and show it onto the screen.

My question is a similar one but adding a variation.

Imagine that you have in a file:

> michael;man;25,34,12,34

My question is, how can you take this line and save the numbers, and only the numbers in some array?

I have been trying the typical thing of read the line and show it for doing some tests, but I can't find how to keep this part in some array:

```
const int NUMBEROFLINES = 4;
FILE *fp
int i;
char leer[100] = "";

    fp = fopen("name.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
       perror("ERROR");
    }
  for (i=0;i<NUMBEROFLINES;i++)
  {
   fgets(read, 100, fp);
   puts(read);
   read[strlen(leer)] = '\0';
} 
close(fp);
```

Comment: Please be more specific; do you want to save each of these numbers in an array of `int`s, or do you want an array of strings that would contain the substring after the second semicolon?

Comment: Please don't post uncompilable, not properly intended code. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to convert each string that is a number into a number and store this number into an array. 
I also assume that your file contains multiple lines as you have a constant saying there are 4 lines. 
It seems like you do not have much experience with c, or programming, or stackoverflow or google, so I'll post an example program which does what i assume you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    // assuming we know how many lines we have and there is a constant number of numbers per such line
    const int NUMBEROFLINES = 4;
    const int NUMBERS_PER_LINE = 4;

    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    // we count the numbers we found
    int numbers = 0;
    // we create an array big enaugh to store the amount of numbers we think we will find
    size_t arraySize = NUMBEROFLINES * NUMBERS_PER_LINE;
    long* array = malloc(sizeof(long) * arraySize);
    // if malloc failed (there is not enough memory) we stop
    if(array == NULL){
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fp = fopen("PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE/input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -2;

    // we read each line into a pointer line and store in len how long that line was
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        // we have a pointer that will contain the single parts separated by , or ;
        char* numberS = line;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            // when we find , or ; we replace it by '\0' so that the word in numberS ends there
            if(line[i] == ';' || line[i] == ','){
                line[i] = '\0';
                char *endptr;
                // we try to convert our string in numberS to a number
                long number = strtol(numberS, &endptr, 10);
                // if endptr and numberS are the same, there was no number in numberS
                if(endptr != numberS){
                    // we try to put our new number to the array
                    if(numbers < arraySize){
                        array[numbers++] = number;
                    } else {
                        // if the array is full we alloc more memory (twice as much)
                        array = realloc(array, 2 * arraySize);
                        // if realloc fails we quit
                        if(array == NULL){
                            printf("realloc failed");
                            return -3;
                        } else {
                            arraySize = 2 * arraySize;
                            array[numbers++] = number;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // our new word starts after the , or ; we just found
                numberS = line + i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Your numbers are:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers; i++){
        printf("%ld\n", array[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to get the tokens delimited by `;` and then you could either use [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)  or write your own function to loop over chars in every token string and check if each char is a numeric digit (ASCII code compare). If the string is all numeric chars, save it to an array, otherwhise don't.